# how to pass data from one php page to another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am building three php pages interlinking with each other 
for eg.
1. Customer details
2. product details
3. payment details
same procedure or mechanism that are provided at every on-line shopping websites.
Now all I just need to pass or hold the data/values that are filled by any user at first form i.e. on customer profile page to second form i.e. on product details without submitting or inserting data into database, and the value of second page i.e. of product details with the data of first page should be pass to third page i.e on payment details, now while clicking on the submit button of third page the whole data or values of all three pages should be stored or inserted finally into database.
I know php provides the method for this and I have used GET and POST method for this also but its  is not at all
Here is my code-
For first page-

```
  <HTML>
     <head>
       <?php
            $value1 = trim($_POST[name]);
        $value2 = trim($_POST[address]);
    $value3= trim($_POST[city]);
        ?>
     </head>
     <body>
       <form action="secondpage.php" method="POST">
         //content of form
        <?php
           echo "<a href='secondpage.php?name=" . $value1 . " && address=" . $value2 .              " && city=" . $value3 . "'><input type='button' value='Proceed To Customer Profile!!!' class='submit' style='cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;' />";
           ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: cannot get your codes. Have you tried to use sessions?

Comment: for that you can create temporary  row in database  and destroy it after submit successful or you can use session but it have limited space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two methods:
1- store every page form info in user session. you can do this by using $_SESSION PHP variable. But note that you must call session_start before using this.

```
$_SESSION["PAGE1"] = array (
    'var1' => 'value1', 
    'var2' => 'value3', 
    ....
);
```

2- You can put a hidden input in every page for and serialize data collectedfrom other pages into this hidden input. you can optionally choose base64_decode/base64_encode and json_encode/json_decode to serialize your data or you can use PHP builtin serialize/unserialize functions.

```
$serializedData = base64_encode ( json_encode ( $_POST ) );
$originalData = json_decode ( base64_decode ( $serializedData ) );
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: hey @user1058125 using this method is there any need to make previous  page's data hidden in next page??

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by

1. Temporarily inserting the data to the database and then removing it later.Its the most efficient way.
2. Store it in a `$_SESSION[]` variable and access it throughout the session of the user
3. The most inefficient method will be to chain the data through the three web pages by using just the GET method and hiding the irrelevant data in `<input type='hiden' value='$val'>`
4. Store them in files or cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can store values in session in multidimensional array like below:

```
 $_SESSION['customer_details'] 
 $_SESSION['Product_details'] 
 $_SESSION['Payment_Details']
```

You can store store all the details of customer details as

```
$_SESSION['customer_details']['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['customer_details']['email'] = $_POST['email'];
```

same for rest of the pages. Once you get the confirmation from payment getway you can store/ insert the values in database.

Answer (score -2):

First of all please learn to format your question, it will really fetch you good answers, secondly for passing the data from `page1` to `page2` to `page3` the best you can use to store the user's data is by using `$_SESSION` and later you can `unset` it after he is done with the form submission

Comment: Don't know but I +1. Maybe it was downvoted because you don't explain how to use sessions. Update answer with using session_start(), setting data example and unsetting example perhaps?